# Shiny R: RowReorder, reordering all values not only first one

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have simple `Shiny app` with `DT table`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

iris2 = head(iris, 30)


server <- function(input, output) {
    output$tb <-DT::renderDataTable(server=FALSE,{
        datatable(
            iris2,
            colnames = c(colnames(iris2)), extensions = 'RowReorder',
            options = list(rowReorder = TRUE))
    })
}


ui <- fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tb', width = '200px', height = '200px'))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, when I try to adjust the table row **only the first column** changes the position. It is probably related to the configuration of the `ReorderRow`, as described [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowReorder.dataSrc). Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement JavaScript into the Shiny app, especially datatable options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to add the row names and sort the table on them, as mentioned in the [github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/624). The working solutions requires only adding `order = list(list(0, 'asc'))` in the `DT options`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

iris2 = head(iris, 30)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tb <-DT::renderDataTable(server=FALSE,{
    datatable(
      iris2,
      colnames = c(colnames(iris2)), extensions = 'RowReorder',
      options = list(order = list(list(0, 'asc')), rowReorder = TRUE))
  })
}


ui <- fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tb', width = '200px', height = '200px'))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```